# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException after creating list view with >100 items

Tags: java, android, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

After creating a list view containing over 100 items (111 to be precise) and deploying the app, it runs as expected but as soon as I scroll through my list, the app crashes and an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is returned. I really don't understand why the length and index are returning '19'. Does anyone know why 19 is shown? What needs to be done to resolve this issue?

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=19; index=19
>               at com.helloapps.helloworldapp.adapters.OrangeListAdapter.getPositionForSection(OrangeListAdapter.java:160)

**XML**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"/>
```

**Java**

```
public class OrangeListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable, SectionIndexer {

    private List<Orange> mData;
    private List<Orange> mFilteredData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemFilter mFilter;

    private Object[] mSections;
    private int[] mSectionsIndexedByPosition;
    private int[] mPositionsIndexedBySection;

    public OrangeListAdapter (List<Orange> data, Context context) {
        mData = data;
        mFilteredData = new ArrayList(mData);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        setupSections();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFilteredData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Orange getItem(int position) {
        return mFilteredData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_dualline, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            holder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_description);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Orange orange = getItem(position);
        holder.title.setText(orange.getName());
        holder.description.setText(orange.getDescrption());
        if (orange.isSelected()) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6600"));
            holder.title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            holder.description.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        } else {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            holder.title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            holder.description.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B5B5B5"));
        }

        holder.title.setText(mFilteredData.get(position).getStation());
        holder.description.setText(mFilteredData.get(position).getZone());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (mFilter == null) {
            mFilter = new ItemFilter();
        }
        return mFilter;
    }

    /**
     * View holder
     */
    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView title;
        private TextView description;
    }

    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(constraint)) {
                results.count = mData.size();
                results.values = new ArrayList(mData);
            } else {
                //Create a new list to filter on
                List<Orange> resultList = new ArrayList<Orange>();
                for (Orange str : mData) {
                    if (str.getStation().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        resultList.add(str);
                    }
                }
                results.count = resultList.size();
                results.values = resultList;
            }
            return results;
        }

        /**
         * Runs on ui thread
         * @param constraint the constraint used for the result
         * @param results the results to display
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results.count == 0) {
                mFilteredData.clear();
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            } else {
                mFilteredData = (ArrayList<Orange>)results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            setupSections();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
        return mPositionsIndexedBySection[section];
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        return mSectionsIndexedByPosition[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getSections() {
        return mSections;
    }

    private void setupSections() {
        String initial = "\0";
        List<String> sections = new ArrayList<String>();
        mSectionsIndexedByPosition = new int[mFilteredData.size()];
        mPositionsIndexedBySection = new int[mFilteredData.size()];

        int section = 0;
        for (int pos = 0; pos < mFilteredData.size(); pos++) {
            Orange orange = mFilteredData.get(pos);
            if (initial.charAt(0) != orange.getName().charAt(0)) {
                initial = orange.getName().substring(0, 1);
                section = sections.size();
                sections.add(initial);
                mPositionsIndexedBySection[section] = pos;
                mSectionsIndexedByPosition[pos] = section;
            } else {
                mSectionsIndexedByPosition[pos] = section;
            }
        }
        mSections = sections.toArray();
        mPositionsIndexedBySection = Arrays.copyOf(mPositionsIndexedBySection, mSections.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: it is the section 19, not number of items, and the array out of bound happens on `mPositionsIndexedBySection`

Answer (score 0):

Your array declared to have only 19 places, that means you can access maximum index of 18 as in arrays index starts with 0, but in above code you are accessing 19th index, then it will complain that your index is out of bound that is 18.

This line looks problematic to me:

```
mPositionsIndexedBySection = Arrays.copyOf(mPositionsIndexedBySection, mSections.length);
```

`**To solve the problem**`: Ensure that you are putting things in an array based on its size. If arrays has size n i.e. 19 then you are supposed to put element only till n-1 index i.e. 18.

Comment: The array size isn't 19 it's the number of items in my list i.e. 111

Answer (score 0):

Fast Scroller only read your sections from `SectionIndexer.getSections()` once, and will not change afterwards.

So the problem seems to occur when your first list contains over 19 sections, and afterwards reload a list where you want to reduce the number of sections to less than 19, which reduce the size of `mPositionsIndexedBySection` as well.

Because the Fast Scroller still remember the old sections, and try to get the position of the 19th section, error occurs.

To solve the problem, have fixed number of sections containing all posible section, only change the `mPositionsIndexedBySection` and `mSectionsIndexedByPosition` on data change.

**Edit:**

Check the link below on how to properly implements `SectionIndexer`

http://androidopentutorials.com/android-listview-fastscroll/

http://responsiveandroid.com/2013/04/13/android-sectionindexer-with-alphabet.html

Comment: What number is recommended?

Comment: It depends what you use as section. A-Z  and a-z? would you use 0-9 ? how about other characters?

Comment: You have to list all possible sections as your section

Comment: I only use letters, no numbers at all.

Comment: You have to understand the fundamental, I have added a link on my post on how SectionIndexer should be implemented, please take a look.

Comment: if you have only A-Z then you need to set `getSections` to always return an array of size 26 with **A-Z**, and you have to change your code in how `mPositionsIndexedBySection` and `mSectionsIndexedByPosition ` are created.

Comment: OK, I must point out that it won't always be A-Z as letters for items that don't being with a certain letter will not be included + I'm not using a section indexer, I'm using a fast scroll indicator.

Comment: Thanks for "pointing out", I must point out that `SectionIndexer` must use FIXED sections, that's all, good luck, I have to go to bed.

Comment: OK, ignore what I said. I got confused with terminology.